# How to implement Monte Carlo simulations in a composite measurement?

Tags: time-series, simulation, monte-carlo, biostatistics, ecology

I hope you can help me with a question regarding Monte Carlo simulations. Though reading about this topic quite a bit, I didn’t find a good answer to my question.

I am working on the seasonal changes over time of the individual reproductive success (RS) components of a bird species.

I have 6 different RS components (for which I have descriptors such as mean, survival probabilities; descriptors vary a bit from component to component) for the 1st year survival of a bird population.

Using Monte Carlo simulation I now need to estimate the overall reproductive success of the population based on all 6 RS components, for each day and for each year of the study.

I have difficulties finding out how to implement this in R since most examples of Monte Carlo simulation that I can find are just based on one artificial distribution or similar (e.g. finance).
The few examples I can find that come close to what I need are not documented well, with R code or similar.

Can you please give me advice of how to implement this in R?

What I need is similar to the example here in appendix 2 (last page at this link: http://canuck.dnr.cornell.edu/research/pubs/pdf/age_effects.pdf), where there are different components that are used stochastically to determine the estimated value at a certain age (date in my case). There is no code however, which makes it again difficult to reproduce.

All the Best and thanks a lot in advance!